# ssl validation of the SONOS service

Tags: sonos

We are preparing our service for SONOS.

We have found problem in only one test: ssl_validation.py

Our media files are located in AWS S3 bucket and they are url-signed.

https://.s3amazone.com/folder/file.mp3?Authentication part.

Sonos tests domain https://.s3amazone.com for ssl renegotiation providing the timeout error, which leads to the only one fail in tests. The question is how much it is important before moving APP for verification, or how to avoid this problem?

regards,Krzys

Comment: Your best bet here, IMO, is to implement Cloudfront. With the CF service you can [specify TLS, and the specific ciphers Sonos requires](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html). CF also supports SSL renegotiation. S3 does not, as far as I know. Plus with CF you get the benefit of edge caching so your customers have a better experience on Sonos.

Comment: Thank you @devonlazarus. I came to the same conlusion and CF solution is done and it works perfectly. But we spent two days to make it working without CF since I didn't now how S3 exactly works with SSL . The signing procedure is here: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/code/3514). Thank you.