# Sonos Self-Test : ssl_validation test_support_secure_renegotiation

Tags: sonos

I am currently trying to integrate Sonos to DR (Danish Broadcasting Corporation) and I am also finding that the self test suite is failing the following Sonos self test error.

```
INFO Start Test Case: ssl_validation 
test_support_secure_renegotiation

Failed  ssl_validation test_support_secure_renegotiation    
Instance Messages:  
Fail: There was an exception while scanning the domain (drod05a-
vh.akamaihd.net) for secure session renegotiation: 
sslyze.utils.ctSSL.errors.SSLErrorSSL - error:140E0197:SSL 
routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
```

I have tried to test secure renegotiation with sslyze and I am getting the following response

```
  Session Renegotiation:

  Client-initiated Renegotiation:    OK - Rejected
  Secure Renegotiation:              OK - Supported
```

In the following references to what looks like an identical problems, one of the answers is to ignore the failed Sonos self test.

[Another - ssl_validation reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45733033/sonos-self-test-exception-during-secure-renegotiation-test/45870809#45870809%0A)

So my question is - is this still a self test issue and is this still a problem ?

yet another reference to an identical problem ...

[AWS - ssl_validation reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254991/ssl-validation-of-the-sonos-service)

I am confused whether or not this is a bug or a problem with our Sonos integration ?

Can we proceed with the APP verification and registration with this failing test ?

Please help - I am not sure how to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Certain combos of OpenSSL and OS continue to cause issues with SSL tests in the self test. You can ignore these errors.

Comment: Thank you Matt for a quick reply ;-)